# save a webpage with VBS

Tags: http, browser, vbscript

When I use FireFox for "https://twitter.com/search?q=vbs",
all works well and I see the tweets (without ever logging on).  But, when
I try to use the simplest VBS-scripting way with XMLHTTP, it seems like I
am declared a mobile user to Twitter and I don't get search results.  So,
how can I change my VBS code below to make this work?  In principle,
it seems like I should be able to set some objXMLHTTP property to spoof
any browser, but then again, Microsoft probably wouldn't give me this
freedom so easily.  Any comments would be great!

```
strFileURL = "https://twitter.com/search?q=vbs"
strHDLocation = "C:\Users\me\webpages\saved_tweets.html"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
if objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1
  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0
  Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  if objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
end if
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: AFAIK vbscript only works in IE.

Comment: "IE vs Firefox" is irrelevant here (and I just confirmed that IE shows search results the same as Firefox with the above link).  I actually want to use neither, but VBS instead, which is the point of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could fake a User Agent (browser) in your HTTP request so that Twitter will consider your browser as a desktop with something like this :

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20131011 Firefox/23.0"
objXMLHTTP.send()
```

Comment: The request must be opened before the request header can be set. With that change the above seems to work, although it didn't when I tried the same with a slightly different user-agent yesterday. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Would using the mobile search page be an option?

```
strFileURL = "https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=vbs"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send
```

Comment: Well, thanks, I suppose they are the same and just checked that your VBS does indeed work.  But, I fear the mobile version might somehow truncate results, so I'd still like to keep this question open for a few days to see if there is a method to truly spoof the browser.